# Creating a dataset with the unique values of indexed variable

Tags: sas

I have a dataset (`LRG_DS`) with about 74,000,000 observations. The dataset has been indexed by a variable (`I_VAR1`) that has about 7500 unique values. I've discovered this by running a proc contents on the dataset.

I'd like to create a dataset (`TEMP`)contains just the 7000 unique values of the index variable.

I've tried the following:

```
data TEMP; 
   set LRG_DS (keep = I_VAR1);  
   by I_VAR1;   
   if first.I_VAR1; 
   run;
```

and

```
proc sort data = LRG_DS nodupkey out = TEMP (keep = I_VAR1); 
   by I_VAR1;
   run;
```

The first approach takes about 46 seconds and the second takes about 55 seconds.

I've read that the sas7bndx is file is not intended to be examined in isolation, but rather as a file to speed up the some of the procedures performed using the index variable.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How fast does a basic PROC SQL take? `proc sql; create table want as select distinct i_var1 from lrg_ds;quit;`

Comment: What is the question ?  Your Data step has keep= on the incoming data, and the Sort step has the keep= on the outgoing data.  Use OPTIONS MSGLEVEL=I FULLSTIMER to better understand the resource utilization occurring during a step.

Comment: @Reeza running the PROC SQL statement takes 55 seconds.

Comment: @Richard thanks for that suggestion. I hadn't come across that option.  Is there a reason you suspect the keep statement is slowing down the code?

Comment: I think the point is that the codes is not comparable since in one you filter on the input and in the other you filter it on the output step. Move the data set keep option to the input data set to speed it up.

Comment: @Richard, moving the statement to the keep option on the data step approach slows it down to about 55 seconds.

Comment: I doubt you can speed it up since it probably needs to read the full dataset.  What are the range of possible values for the key variable?  Perhaps it is easier to generate all possible values and then use the index to test which one's exist.

Comment: @Tom There are about 12 million possible values. Clever idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YMMV but using populating an empty hash table with the unique key values may perform better than a sort.

Create some example data:

```
data x;
  do cnt=1 to 10*100000;
    var=round(rand('uniform'),0.001);
    do cnt2=1 to 10;
      output;
    end;
    drop cnt2;
  end;
run;
```

Test speed with a `proc sort`:

```
proc sort data=x(keep=var) out=sorted nodupkey;
  by var;
run;
```

Compare with the hash table version:

```
data _null_;

   set x(keep=var) end=eof;

   if _n_ eq 1 then do;
     declare hash ht ();
     rc = ht.DefineKey ('var');
     rc = ht.DefineDone ();
   end; 
   if ht.check() ne 0 then do;
     rc = ht.add();   
   end;
   if eof then do;
     ht.output(dataset:"ids");
   end;
run;
```

From my very brief tests, I found that the hash table version starts to perform worse as the number of unique values grows.  It may be possible to offset this by dimensioning the hash appropriately beforehand but I didn't test.